# how can I not lose the output of my foreachR midway?

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I am used to running for loops and is quite satisfied with them , I do a big function(one step forecasting for many models and iterates over thousand of skus/research)

then I searched around and found the foreach and parallel processing , as in the for loop I make an external list and save the sequential output in this list, I can stop the loop and check my output and then continue , but I failed to do so with foreach.

I tried the .verbose =TRUE in the foreach argument to know how long is remaining but to no success.

is there a way to prevent losing all the output if I stop the foreach midway?

would you please provide me with a sample code, much appreciated , you are saving a lot of research hours.

Comment: Why about storing the outputs on disk?

Comment: Hi F.Prive, I cannot see the output until the foreach ends , or at least I do not know how . my code is as below :   ** operat1<- foreach(i= 1:4000,.verbose = TRUE,.errorhandling = 'pass') %dopar% forecasting(i)** 'code' what if I stop it at 2000, operat1 results to NULL

Comment: I was thinking about using something like `runonce::save_run()` (disclaimer: I'm the author) so that you do not have to rerun what was already run before you stopped it.

Comment: that's awesome , I will give it a shot and let you know. thanks a lot F.Prive.

Comment: I came across similar problem and tried to implement it. If stopped midway the file created as backup isn't stored. Here's how I tried: `library(foreach); library(runonce)
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
tmp <- tempfile(tmpdir = getwd(), fileext = ".rds")
save_run({
opr <- foreach(i = 1:30000, .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
  sqrt(i)
}
},file = tmp)
` If the authors could provide an update, I will greatly appreciate it.